# Java - new NewThread()

Tags: java

В одной из книг даются примеры и мне не совсем понятно использование кодового слова "new".

Пример 1:

```
// Create a second thread.
class NewThread implements Runnable {
  Thread t;

  NewThread() {
    // Create a new, second thread
    t = new Thread(this, "Demo Thread");
    System.out.println("Child thread: " + t);
    t.start(); // Start the thread
  }

  // This is the entry point for the second thread.
  public void run() {
    try {
      for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println("Child Thread: " + i);
        Thread.sleep(500);
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("Child interrupted.");
    }
    System.out.println("Exiting child thread.");
  }
}

class ThreadDemo {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new NewThread(); // create a new thread

    try {
      for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println("Main Thread: " + i);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("Main thread interrupted.");
    }
    System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
  }
}
```

Пример 2

```
// Create a second thread by extending Thread
class NewThread extends Thread {

  NewThread() {
    // Create a new, second thread
    super("Demo Thread");
    System.out.println("Child thread: " + this);
    start(); // Start the thread
  }

  // This is the entry point for the second thread.
  public void run() {
    try {
      for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println("Child Thread: " + i);
        Thread.sleep(500);
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("Child interrupted.");
    }
    System.out.println("Exiting child thread.");
  }
}

class ExtendThread {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new NewThread(); // create a new thread

    try {
      for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println("Main Thread: " + i);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("Main thread interrupted.");
    }
    System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
  }
}
```

В методе main вызывается оператор "new NewThread()". Почему предварительно не создается ссылочная переменная, а ей уже не присваивается ссылка на объект создаваемый оператором new?

Просто до этого встречал такие примеры "Test t1 = new Test();".

Comment: а что именно не понятно? Вас же не смущает `System.out.println("Main Thread: " + i);` хотя конструкция примерно такая же. создания объекта и сразу его использование без сохранения ссылки.

Comment: Не понял аналогии с `sout`. `println()` - статический метод, он не требует создания переменной.

Comment: к этим потокам не требуется обращаться в дальнейшем, поэтому им не нужна ссылка, по которой к ним можно было бы обратиться, но если вам будет спокойнее, в можете использовать "классическую" конструкцию с присвоением созданного объекта ссылке, хотя надобности в ней никакой нет. Подробнее смотрите про анонимные классы

Comment: @v6v, я тоже по Шилдту учился. Хорошая книга!

Answer (score 3):

В вашем примере ссылочная переменная не создается, поскольку она больше нигде не используется. Если вы хотите использовать ссылочную переменную, то надо писать что-то наподобие

```
 Thread t = new NewThread();
 t.start();
```

и убрать вызов `start()` из конструктора.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81942/discussion-on-answer-by-roman-c-java-new-newthread).

Answer (score 0):

В этих примерах просто необходимо создать и запустить поток. Больше к нему не требуется доступ. Если бы мы потом захотели проверить состояние потока или получить его имя, то мы бы создали переменную и через нее проводили бы все операции. А так нам надо создать и запустить. Создаем с помощью `new`, а запускается поток прямо в конструкторе.

Comment: есть оффициальное определение - анонимный класс

Comment: Анонимный класс - это нечто другое. В данном примере создается экземпляр класса, а не анонимный класс.

Comment: А сборщик "мусора" не должен прибрать создаваемый объект не имеющий ссылки?

Comment: экземпляр класса создается в любом случае, но анонимный класс не имеет ссылки на этот экземпляр. Просто в вопросе реализация какая то - через зад. создание потока в конструкторе класса, который и создается анонимным. можно было проще все реализовать, сделать [анонимным сам поток](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9625136/7566397), а не создавать полноценный объект в конструкторе и вызывать его анонимно.

Comment: @pavlofff, в вопросе, если вы заметили, показаны 2 "стратегии" создания потока - расширение `Thread` и реализация `Runnable`. Для второго случая как раз показан классический прием, когда вместо создания 3-этажных структур просто передается ссылка `this` конструктору класса `Thread`. Причина не делать анонимным сам поток - например, вызвыть у этого потока какой-нибудь метод (`join()`, `interrupt()` итд).

Comment: да все равно примеры какие то .. надуманые, кто то так делает в реальной разработке что ли ... ps: ответ ваш в принципе правильный, не знаю кто его минусует.

Comment: Учебные примеры все надуманные )))

Comment: @v6v нет, этот класс не будет уничтожен GC пока под уничтожение не попадет основной класс, в котором он создан, так как данный класс все равно имеет неявную ссылку для внешнего класса, хоть мы ее и не сохранили для себя.

Comment: Давайте разберемся с `GC`. В первом случае объект `NewThread`создан, в его конструкторе создается `поток`, внутри которого будет храниться ссылка на `NewThread`. Соответственно, если до объекта можно добраться из "корневой точки", значит объект жив и его убивать нельзя - `gc` отдыхает. Во втором случае мы уже являемся объектом типа `Thread`, т.е., тоже создается поток. Теперь последнее - что такое "корневая точка"? Это:
Локальные переменные и параметры методов;
Java Потоки;
Статические переменные;
Ссылки из JNI;
Т.о., из потока можно добраться до нашего объекта, значит gc курит в сторонке

Comment: @v6v, не совсем так. Этот объект попадет под уничтожение тогда, когда закончит свою работу поток (см выше мои детальные объяснения). Тогда уничтожится сам объект потока и все, на что он имел ссылки, т.е. на наш объект `NewThread`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81936/discussion-between---and-pavlofff).